# What is wrong with my linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to create a class for nodes (it's suppsoed to be a system for a queue) to `import` in another program. I know that the other program is working fine since it works when `import`ing another type of queue that uses the same function names(that is based on Pythons regular `list`). With this queue-type however, I never seem to be able to get it to work. I'm sure that there are MANY problems with my code(Since I've been getting a big variety of error messages) and I would like some input on what i should change.

Here is the code for the class:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, v=None, n=None):
        self.item=v
        self.next=n

    lastnode=__init__

    def put(self, v):
        Node.lastnode.next=self
        self.item=v
        self.next=None
        Node.lastnode=Node.lastnode.next

    def get(self):
        if Node.isempty(self):
            return None
        out=Node.__init__.next
        Node.__init__.next=out.next
        out.next=None
        return ut.item

    def isempty(self):
        if Node.lastnode==Node.__init__:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The `put` functions role is to put a new item/node last in the queue.

The `get` functions role is to remove the first node from the queue and `return` its item.

The `isempty` function is there to check if the queue is empty.

Please give me some criticism on this.

Comment: You question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW: Remember that builtins are highly optimized - if you want to use your solution in real-life app, use standard list, and if you have good reasons not to use it, prototype it in python, and then write C extension for you data structure.

Comment: Yea, I guessed as much, this is merely for learning the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you're trying to use a single class to solve a problem that really requires two classes.  Linked lists involve two kinds of items:  The nodes and the list structure itself.  A node only "knows" two things: the data it contains and the identity of the next node it links to.  The list object is what manages access to a group of linked nodes.  By trying to combine the two roles in a single class you're making it impossible to realize a list. Think about, e.g., how your class could manage multiple nodes.  You're trying to get around such difficulties, it seems, by using class attributes for list-level data (such as the identity of the head node), but even if that could be made to work you'd only be able to work with one list instance at a time.

In addition to this, your code has some basic syntactical issues.  E.g., the line `lastnode=__init__` does not call `__init__`; call syntax would be `lastnode=__init__()`, but you can't do that in the body of the class definition.

Here's a trivial implementation you could study:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class List(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def put(self, value):
        new = Node(value)
        new.next = self.head
        self.head = new

    def get(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            return None
        old = self.head
        self.head = old.next
        return old.value

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None
```